# Как объединить в группу выделенные фигуры fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Как объединить в группу выделенные фигуры fabric.js

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/254763/

Comment: Это я видел, но мне надо добавить в группу не известное заранее колличество объектов